# Unity how to get masked texture and save as png

Tags: unity-game-engine, mask

Hi I am using mask in unity and now I want to get the masked texture and save as a png file.

Unity Mask
[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3gpXmo8zRo)

For example, in this video, I want to get the masked image instead of the whole background image or the mask texture.

I tried `(GetComponent<Mask>().graphic.mainTexture as Texture2D).GetPixels()` but it doesn't work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you need to calculate the output texture by yourself. By this I mean you need to take image and mask image and make transparent the pixels of image according to mask.

Answer (score 1):

Here is implementation of what I said in comment.

Note that, mask's texture need to have same dimensions as image texture to make below code work properly. Otherwise you need to calculate which pixels overlap with mask and which not.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetMaskedImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image img;
    public Image mask;

    public RawImage outputImg;

    void Start () 
    {
        Texture2D output = new Texture2D(img.sprite.texture.width, img.sprite.texture.height);
        for (int i = 0; i < img.sprite.texture.width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.sprite.texture.height; j++)
            {
                if (mask.sprite.texture.GetPixel(i, j).a > 0.5f)
                    output.SetPixel(i, j, img.sprite.texture.GetPixel(i, j));
                else
                    output.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f));
            }
        }

        output.Apply();

        outputImg.texture = output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, I am doing the same way. It is really inconvenient that I have to calculate every pixel and set to a new texture. I mean, I don't how how unity implements the mask function. But since it is just implemented, I thought it would be very easy to get the masked texture...  Anyway, thank you for your suggestion and sharing!

Comment: I think Unity Mask component does it on shader level, so there is no storage in heap of that texture. But it is just my quess.